# NewtonSoft.Json NuGet v11.0.1-beta3 not working with .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: visual-studio, json.net, .net-standard

Using Visual Studio 2017 15.5.5, I created a .NET Standard (2.0) Class Library.

To this, I added the NuGet package "Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.1-beta3" (the latest full version does not seem to support .NET Standard 2.0).  When I go to the package location, I see the following file:

> ~.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.1-beta3\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll

However, when executing the code (in **RELEASE** mode only), I get the following exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

My project file contains:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.1-beta3" />
```

The only way I could get this to work was to un-install the NuGet package and  then reference the DLL directly.  This is obviously not very satisfactory since NuGet offers so many advantages.

Suggestions?

**EDIT**
Discovered that this only manifests itself in RELEASE mode.  In DEBUG mode, all unit tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add [dependentAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/dependentassembly-element) to your `app.config` file.

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-11.0.0.0" newVersion="11.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: The DLL didn't have an app.config file, so created one, but that had no effect.  I did discover that this only occurs when in RELEASE mode.